Automated recurring files into BigQuery
I work for a small marketing agency, we're transitioning out of Domo and storing our data in BigQuery.
Clients send us recurring files on a regular but not exactly scheduled basis. Usually things like invoices - what they're selling, revenue, who's buying, that sort of thing.
Big problem I'm having is trying to find a way to get these into GBQ automatically. Ideally new files sent in would append onto the previous rows.
Been working at this for months, at a bit of a dead end. Part of the problem is my skills - basic SQL but that's really it - no python or anything like that. Been at the company for a year and everyone on the team before me quit so now I'm the old head and I have no choice but to figure it out.
Where we're at right now is sending an email with the files attached to Zapier. Zapier sorts the file based on the sender and puts it in a corresponding Google Drive folder. From there Hevo sends it to BigQuery. This process has worked for some but it can be inconsistent and I'm willing to branch out.
Also, because of the above, any tips on things I should research/courses I should take to deal with my lack of support at work would be very helpful.
Thanks y'all.

It's a pretty long process.
First, define your data sources. For common data sources like Facebook API, or SQL databases you can use ingestion products like Fivetran, Airbyte or tools like Ingestr.
For customer specific APIs, business logic, etc, you should use a scripting language like Python.
When you have to schedule a script, you need a computer/server to run it. You can manually everyday, or you can use a cloud function environment like AWS Lambda to run them.
When you need more complex workflows and scheduling is not enough, you need an orchestrator. Orchestrators run your workflow in the right time based on the dependencies. An Orchestrator like Airflow, Prefect or Bruin might be useful at that point.
You'll need to run SQL scripts, as well. Then it comes to the transformation. You can use BigQuery Scheduled Tasks for basic workflows. If it becomes complex, you can schedule them in orchestrators as well.
Finally, to manage complex SQL pipelines, you need a transformation product like DBT, SQL Mesh or Bruin.
It'll give you the whole pipeline automation for a long time.
